# google maps not working

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to display a map in a fragment, this fragment is made visible if the user select a tab, this tab is contained in another fragment contained in MainActivity. The fragment that shows the map extends from SupportMapFragment.

I followed the instructions provided by android developers and it worked, in the beginning. Due to some changes caused by android versions incompatibility: actionBar, viewPager... I quit the library and relink it ( in two ways: first doing the link from the library project and since it didn't work, deleting the library project and reimported it and add the library to my project. Hope this explanation can be understood and don't mess it up).

First log-cat asked me to change the manifest's metadata to

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gsm.version"
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

I did that and it repeat the error:

```
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.comercio/com.comercio.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the right value.  Expected 4030500 but found 0.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.n(Unknown Source)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.v(Unknown Source)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.q.u(Unknown Source)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(Unknown Source)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.cE(Unknown Source)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$b.a(Unknown Source)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreate(Unknown Source)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreate(Unknown Source)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1477)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5143)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
12-18 08:36:27.589: E/AndroidRuntime(1613):     ... 11 more
```

Manifest

```
<meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gsm.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<permission
    android:name="com.comercio.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I've looked for the answer here and everywhere and can't find the fix to this.

Thanks for your help

Comment: the `meta-data` needs to be in your application tag

Comment: it is, i only write the things that i consider relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have misspelled gms with gsm. It should be like this:

```
<meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"     />
```